# Split a RDD into Multiple RDD based on value without doing `collect()` and `filter()`

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, amazon-emr

I want to split an RDD into multiple RDD based on a value in a row. The values in rows are pre-known and are fixed in nature.

for e.g.

```
source_rdd = sc.parallelize([('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',4),('b',5),('b',6)])
```

should be split into two RDDs with one containing only `a` and another containing only `b` as keys

1. I have tried `groupByKey` method and able to do it successfully after doing a `collect()` operation on grouped RDD, which I cannot do in production due to memory constraints

```
a_rdd, b_rdd = source_rdd.keyBy(lambda row: row[0]).groupByKey().collect()
```

2. The current implementation is to apply multiple filter operation to get each RDD

```
a_rdd = source_rdd.filter(lambda row: row[0] == 'a')
b_rdd = source_rdd.filter(lambda row: row[0] == 'b')
```

Can this be optimized further, what will be the best way to do it in production with data which cannot fit in memory?

**Usage:** These RDD will be converted into different Dataframes (one for each key), each with different schema and stored in S3 as output.

**Note:** I would prefer `pyspark` implementation. I have read a lot of stack overflow answers and blogs, and could not find anyway which is working for me yet.

I have already seen question which is marked duplicate for, which I have already mentioned in my question. I have asked this question as the provided solution seems not the most optimised way and is 3 years old.

Comment: @eliasah I have already seen question which is marked duplicate for, which I have already mentioned in my question. I have asked this question as the provided solution seems not the most optimised way and is 3 years old.

Comment: Person who downvoted the question can you please comment the reason, so either I can improve or defend my question

Comment: If the duplicate has outdated answers, don't ask a new question, instead you can place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the older question. *Current answers are outdated* is a valid and preselectable [bounty reason](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/). There are also high-rep users who are willing to spend their rep on such things if you ask nicely, you just have to find them in chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `toDF` too. Aslo, `a_rdd` and `b_rdd` are not `rdd` in your code as they are collected!

```
df = source_rdd.keyBy(lambda row: row[0]).groupByKey()
a_rdd = df.filter(lambda row: row[0] == 'a')
b_rdd = df.filter(lambda row: row[0] == 'b')
```

Comment: This method still need to scan whole DataFrame each time a new condition is required, which I want to avoid

Comment: @SumitKumar If you don't wanna dataframes, using a filter over the rdd directly (the answer is updated).

Comment: Now it is same as my implementation which I want to further optimise if possible. Details are present in my question body

Comment: @SumitKumar Nope. it is not the same. You collect it! but I am not. Directly applied filter over rdd.

Comment: collect is one of the methodology, I am already using second methodology, same as yours which does not use any `collect` or `groupBy`